# invalid regular expression in gsub

Tags: regex, r, gsub

Why is the email `regex` giving an `error` of `invalid regular expression '^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$', reason 'Invalid character range'`

```
blogs.smpl <- "mail:mami@yahoo.com: subject:Lorem Ipsum body:   is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s"

blogs.smpl <- gsub("^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$","",blogs.smpl)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `-` should only be at the start or end of a character class. Otherwise, it means a ranges between the symbol before it, and after it.

Last character class is faulty: `[a-zA-Z0-9-.]`. It must be turned to `[a-zA-Z0-9.-]`.

NOTE: In R, you cannot escape a hyphen inside a character class to match a literal hyphen, unless you use `perl=TRUE`.

Also, see the [R String Manipulation](http://www3.nd.edu/~sjones20/JonesUND/BioStats_files/RstringManipulation_2-6-13.pdf) PDF for more information on R character classes (Page 2) and regexes in general. Here is an excerpt:

> Here is a set of rules on how to match characters as regular
>   characters inside a character class: To match `]` inside a character
>   class put it first.
>
> To match `-` inside a character class put it first
>   or last.
>
> To match `^` inside a character class put it anywhere, but first.
>
> To match any other character or metacharacter (but `\`) inside a
>   character class put it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is this section:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9-.]
```

Try putting the dash last like so:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9.-]
```